# Using selector for local function

Tags: swift

I want to set up a timer that would trigger some local function, so that count and scheduledAction() are not visible to outside. In the following case, scheduledAction is an unrecognized selector. What would be a good way to do this?

```
func SomeFunc() {
    var count = 0
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "scheduledAction", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    func scheduledAction() {
        count++
        if count < 10 {
            // do something
        }
        else {
            timer = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I know where is the problem , is it that you want them to be private , so that not every class or method can access it ? , or is it that scheduledAction is not recognized , if so , what's the error message

Comment: The error message is XXXClass.scheduledAction: unrecognized selector. james' solution below needs to create an extra class. I wonder if this is a way to use closure/nested function to achieve this.

Comment: You selector is actually not reachable. There is no self as you do not have a class, struct nor enum.

Answer (score 1):

The function scheduledAction should be outside the body of SomeFunc, i.e:

```
func SomeFunc() {
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "scheduledAction", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func scheduledAction() {

}
```

The self in the target parameter of 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval' refers to the class that contains SomeFunc.

If you want to access the timer variable in the selector, you would need to use the selector "scheduledAction:" and have the scheduledAction take an NSTimer argument e.g.

```
func SomeFunc() {
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "scheduledAction", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func scheduledAction(timer : NSTimer) {

}
```

But the much better pattern would be to encapsulate it as a class:

```
class SomeClass() {
    var count = 0
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "scheduledAction", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    func scheduledAction() {
        count++
        if count < 10 {
            // do something
        }
        else {
            timer = nil
        }
    }
}
```

To have it so the count and scheduledAction are not visible to the outside, just mark them as private!

Comment: `timer` won't be visible in the `scheduledAction` scope. You could change your selector to `"scheduledAction:"` and your signature to `func scheduledAction(timer: NSTimer)` so that it receives the timer instance.

Comment: Yes didn't see that, will update accordingly... thanks